# Is there a way to detect user's actions on a webpage for Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to trigger some event on my extension whenever

- the website page is loaded
- user navigates on the same page by clicking
  some links

The first, I can accomplish with:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(...)
```

But it does not trigger when the user click something to navigate through the page. (it's a single-page application)

Comment: can you put it on the `activeTab` ?

Comment: If the tab's URL doesn't change you'll have to use a click listener or MutationObserver in a content script.

Comment: @wOxxOm yes the URL doesn't change. I couldn't find anything about click listeners on content scripts.

Comment: `click` listener is a standard DOM thing, which you can use in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use click listeners or MutationObservers in your content script.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver/observe